# Ajax POST error using Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel

I want to submit a form of checkboxes that represent the interests of an user. When clicking a checkbox, the value of the checked interest will be sent to the database "Followers" table and the user will begin following that interest. I couldn't find a way to have one form submit multiple rows, so i decided to make each checkbox a different form and use Ajax to send the information as the user goes through the form. However, When i attempt to make a POST using Ajax I get `POST http://localhost/interest net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. or ERR 500. Can someone help me? I don't understand where i'm messing up. here is my code:

i have the meta tag

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

html:

```
{!! Form::open(array('id'=> 'form2')) !!}
                                <div class = "form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::label('title','Title:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::checkbox('interest_id', '2', false, ['class' => 'formclick']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <input id = "submit" type="button" value="Click Me!"  />
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

JS:

```
 var base_url = 'http://localhost';

$('#submit').click(function(){
   var interest = {
       interest_id : $('.formclick').val()
   }
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url+'/interest',
    data: interest,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function() {
       alert('new interest');
    }
});
```

});

InterestController:

```
 public function store(InterestRequest $interest)
{
    $interest = new Follower(array(
        'user_id' => $interest->get('interest_id'),
        'follower_id'  => Auth::id()
    ));

    $interest->save();
}
```

Comment: Is it logging anything to your log file when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use the same variable name for an parameter and a local scope variable.
2. Are you using nginx or apache?
3. Have you setup your .htaccess file right?
4. What do you see when you go to http://localhost/interest/public
5. Enable the Laravel debug mode, there you have much more information which can be of help to you and us.

Comment: 1. Okay, got it!     2. Im using MAMP Apache   3. Not sure, Im using Php Storm with Laravel. I see the ht.access file under the public folder, but i have not made any edits to it.     4.Nothing shows up,  just redirect to yahoo search for the link.     5. under app.php i changed the debug from false to true, now what?    --Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper path of URL to ajax call.

**instead of use:**
    var base_url = 'http://localhost';

**use:** 
    var base_url = '{{ url() }}';

It will resolve your issue